# data entry in mysql databae happens only once.. thereafter it fails

Tags: php

Data entry in mysql database happening only when table is empty. Therafter it fails showing no error.
If i delete added row and try again,  Data is entered in table but not thereafter.

Comment: Cool story. Any code to help diagnosis?

Comment: can you show some code, if missing having primary key issue, what does the error displayed when failed?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show your table structure? and errors you are getting if any?

Solution: It may be due to if your table has unique constraint on any field and you trying to insert same record again.

e.g,

```
table `users` has fields id, name username, password
insert into `users` VALUES(1, "Test", "user1", "123");
insert into `users` VALUES(2, "Test", "user1", "1234");
```

it will not insert record into database.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: Id column is only primary key, which is different in all the cases.

Comment: So, how are you inserting records in the database, can you please add the code or script you using, it will help use to recognize your problem.